# Pandas DataFrame Combinations and expand

Tags: pandas, combinations

I have a DataFrame as shown below and trying to expand it to the combination of 3 people and sum of their total.

```
Person1 Person2 Total
Adam    Adam    0.00
Adam    Jack    5.78
Adam    John    9.43
Adam    Wills   33.78
Adam    Robert  13.43
Adam    Mary    23.95
Adam    Jennifer    7.48
Adam    Patricia    5.15
Jack    Jack    0.00
Jack    John    1.43
Jack    Wills   2.78
Jack    Robert  0.43
Jack    Mary    9.95
Jack    Jennifer    11.48
Jack    Patricia    15.15
```

Expecting outcome

```
Person1 Person2 Person3 Total
Adam    Jack    Mary    39.68 # sum(Adam-Jack + Adam-Mary + Jack-Mary)
...
```

.
Trying of doing like this  but as new to pandas cannot add the total.
Is there a better way to do so..

```
from itertools import combinations

def func(group): 
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(group.Pose, 3)), columns=["Person1", "Person2", "Person3"])
    # missing addition of total.


x =reset_df.groupby('Person1').apply(func)
x.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not mathematically correct: `sum(A,B,C)` is not necessarily equal to `sum(A,B)+sum(A,C)+sum(B,C)`. You should sum from the original data.

Comment: yes, you are right. data are like (Adam-Jack =5.78), like Adam and Jack friendliness=5.78. no single data for A or B or C.its in combination of 2.