# pandas explode rows with all substring combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find all combinations of a substring found in a single column, and then explode the dataframe with all possible combinations of each word.

**Example Dataframe**

```
                     URL                Keyword
0  http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Lightning Sale
1   https://www.ebay.com        Shop eBay Today
```

**Desired Output**

```
                      URL                Keyword
0   http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Lightning Sale
1   http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Sale Lightning
2   http://www.amazon.com  Lightning Amazon Sale
3   http://www.amazon.com  Sale Amazon Lightning
4   http://www.amazon.com  Sale Lightning Amazon
5   http://www.amazon.com  Lightning Sale Amazon
6    https://www.ebay.com        Shop eBay Today
7    https://www.ebay.com        Shop Today eBay
8    https://www.ebay.com        eBay Shop Today
9    https://www.ebay.com        eBay Today Shop
10   https://www.ebay.com        Today eBay Shop
11   https://www.ebay.com        Today Shop eBay
```

**Minimum Reproducable Example**

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'URL': ['http://www.amazon.com', 'https://www.ebay.com'],
        'Keyword': ["Amazon Lightning Sale", "Shop eBay Today"]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
print(df)
```

I've tried the solution here: [Pandas DataFrame Combinations and expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316456/pandas-dataframe-combinations-and-expand) but it's not quite what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way without using itertools:

```
(df.assign(Keyword = df['Keyword'].str.split().map(lambda x: [[i,j,k] for i in x for j in x for k in x if len({i,j,k})==len(x)]))
 .explode('Keyword')
 .assign(Keyword = lambda x: x['Keyword'].str.join(' ')))
```

Output:

```
                     URL                Keyword
0  http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Lightning Sale
0  http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Sale Lightning
0  http://www.amazon.com  Lightning Amazon Sale
0  http://www.amazon.com  Lightning Sale Amazon
0  http://www.amazon.com  Sale Amazon Lightning
0  http://www.amazon.com  Sale Lightning Amazon
1   https://www.ebay.com        Shop eBay Today
1   https://www.ebay.com        Shop Today eBay
1   https://www.ebay.com        eBay Shop Today
1   https://www.ebay.com        eBay Today Shop
1   https://www.ebay.com        Today Shop eBay
1   https://www.ebay.com        Today eBay Shop
```

Comment: Wow this is much faster!

Comment: Ah I just noticed it doesn't give all permutations of each keyword unfortunately.

Comment: sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

1. create an ID for each row

   ```
    #create an id:
    df['ID'] = range(df.shape[0])

                     URL                Keyword      ID
    0  http://www.amazon.com  Amazon Lightning Sale  0
    1   https://www.ebay.com        Shop eBay Today  1
   ```
2. Create the combinations for each row as a new DataFrame, or dict or ...

   ```
   import re
   import itertools
   def create_combinations(id, kw):

       # split the keywords by word:
       words = re.split('\W+', kw)

       return pd.DataFrame([ {'ID':id, 'Combinations' : ' '.join(x) } for x in itertools.permutations(words)])


   # create the combinations
   data = []
   for id, kw in zip(df.ID, df.Keyword):
       data.append( create_combinations(id, kw) )
   ```
3. Join

   ```
   # join the data
   pd.merge(df, pd.concat(data), on = ['ID'])


            URL     Keyword     ID  Combinations
       0    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Amazon Lightning Sale
       1    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Amazon Sale Lightning
       2    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Lightning Amazon Sale
       3    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Lightning Sale Amazon
       4    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Sale Amazon Lightning
       5    http://www.amazon.com   Amazon Lightning Sale   0   Sale Lightning Amazon
       6    https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   Shop eBay Today
       7    https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   Shop Today eBay
       8    https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   eBay Shop Today
       9    https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   eBay Today Shop
       10   https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   Today Shop eBay
       11   https://www.ebay.com    Shop eBay Today     1   Today eBay Shop
   ```

---

Joost Döbken's answer is a bit more elegant

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import permutations

df['Keyword'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: list(permutations(x.split())))
df.explode('Keyword', ignore_index=True)
```

First the [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) method applied to the Keyword column will create all possible combinations of keywords as a list.

Next you can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-explode.php) function to create many items from the created lists.

If you really want a full string instead of a tuple of keywords, you can replace the `list(...)` part with a string join: `[" ".join(t) for t in permutations(x.split())]`